# How to identify scroll (up or down) event on SF1 on iPad for lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

The functionality I want to achieve is, hide/show the footer based on scroll up/down on SF1 on iPad. Is there any way to catch this event and take any action in the controller.

Comment: Why not just use CSS? You should prefer using pure CSS rather than more complicated JavaScript when possible.

Comment: If only CSS, can you guide me to the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [waypoints js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) or any other alternative that helps you triggering an action when you scroll to a certain element.